# Transform an object to a Select Label / Value with API and Laravel 5

Tags: api, laravel

I have an API that return all federations

```
public function getFederations()
{
    return Federation::all();
}
```

So, now, I need all the federations, but I need to insert it in a Select.
I just need the id, name fields.

So, what I should do is:

```
$federations->map(function ($federation) {
   return [
       'text'              => $federation->name,
       'value'             => $federation->id,
   ];
```

But I wouldn't like to create a single function / endpoint for each response format.

Is there a way to do it???

Answer (score 0):

You can add just values that you need to your query and the name that you want, something like this:

```
public function getFederations()
{
    return Federation::all(['id as value', 'name as text']);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What I do in API applications is I make use of `$visible` and `$appends` arrays in my models. For instance, assuming this is your `Federation` model:

```
class Federation extends Eloquent
{
    protected $visible = [
        'text',
        'value',
    ];
    protected $appends= [
        'text',
        'value',
    ]

    public function getTextAttribute()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function getValueAttribute()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }
}
```